# When I asked this type of question, it was immediately migrated

Tags: discussion

My question:
[What do you do when you're fried and can't get any work done?](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/17946/what-do-you-do-when-youre-absolutely-fried-and-cant-get-any-work-done)

The other question: [How can I increase focus when doing something boring?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95638/how-can-i-increase-focus-when-doing-something-boring)

What's with the double standard here? My question was even more specific to the workplace as I do not have the same freedom in the workplace as I do when at home/college etc. The sister site is even called **Personal** Productivity, when my question was very specific to a workplace issue.

I'm not asking to get my question brought back. I'm just asking for uniformity when it comes to closing/migrating questions. Also, if anyone is able to tell me how my question got migrated so fast, that would be excellent.

Comment: In my opinion, both questions belong in the "Personal Productivity" forum. But sometimes moderators get to a question quickly and migrate it, other times they don't and are reluctant to migrate a question which already has a bunch of answers. Don't take it personally, there is a lot of fuzziness about what should be migrated and what should not. Don't expect hard and fast rules or complete consistency. People do the migration, not an algorithm.

Comment: [trouble with popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) @JoeStrazzere - business as usual

Answer (score 3):

I agree there's an inconsistency.

Personally, I think they should both be on The Workplace, because they were asked here and are not Off-Topic (though the second question could have done with a more explicit problem statement, something like "What Actions/Tactics/Things can I do, whilst in the office, to help regain my productivity?").

As originally written, the question is actually not clear (until the final sentence) that your question is specifically about productivity *in an office setting*. And even then is only implied. So I understand how it could have been seen as more of a general Personal Productivity question.

As to how it got migrated so fast, migration happens as soon as enough people vote on it. In your case, that happened to happen very quickly. It's just down to how many people are reviewing the queues at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the issue is more about a lack of standard than a double standard. Your question got two quick close votes for being outside our scope and was then spotted by a moderator who confirmed the close with a migration to [productivity.se]. I'd have probably done the same. Our help scope only talks about interpersonal issues and dealing with workplace problems. None of it mentions "how do I do my actual job tasks better?" so strictly speaking a productivity question is *likely* off-topic. The main meta thread on this seems to be [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2079/is-workplace-productivity-on-topic-on-the-workplace-se), and I agree with Monica's take on it that there's some overlap but there is a fairly clear line that can be drawn.

What happened with the newer question is that no one ended up drawing that line. The question did get an off-topic vote but was kept open in review. It then hit HNQ, gained a lot of popularity and attention which often makes users (and moderators) more hesitant to close it. While I can't speak for the rest of the mod team, I avoid taking unilateral mod action without some community input, especially when it comes to migrations and cases where our scope is only vaguely defined. A single CV followed by a positive review would probably guarantee that I wouldn't mod-close and migrate. A question that very quickly got two close votes and a comment explaining why a question is off-topic on the other hand would give me the confidence to migrate it.

Ultimately, the lack of a [clear migration philosophy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration) is probably the chief culprit for your main question, while the more direct issue in this scenario is that the close votes went in different directions for the two questions.

Comment: In the same time it got the close votes it had also garnered a few up votes. I also believe it made it to HNQ for a short period after being migrated. I just wish there was more consistency to these close votes and that the opinion of just 3 people in a 5 minute window shouldn't be enough to warrant a migration. Although the post got ~2k views, the migration caused it to get much less attention and as a result fewer answers- you may notice that I didn't accept an answer because I honestly didn't get a satisfactory one.

Comment: "the lack of a clear migration philosophy is probably the chief culprit" - this.

Comment: @DCON Conversely if your post had stayed on Workplace and picked up downvotes for being off-topic it would never have reached HNQ. HNQ tends to be a mixed blessing as well as the answers you got because of it aren't ones that I would call high quality. The best way to attract answers is to phrase your post well and concisely, have a clear core question and post it where it's on-topic and within scope. Attracting exposure after the fact can be done with the bounty system.

Comment: But ultimately the fact that you got fewer or less useful answers has no relevance to the off-topic close and migration. I think it's worth raising the issue of inconsistent migration or to discuss whether the mod team acted too fast on this one. But those are two largely separate issues and not getting a good answer isn't pertinent to either of them. I believe the close vote process exists to preserve the Q&A nature of the site and is not concerned with helping the author of the question. The migration process exists for both, though the focus remains on bringing a useful question to a site.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a mistake to think of a migration as a negative. It's not that we don't want the question here or even necessarily that it can't be answered here.  In many cases of migrations (and these 2 in particular), another exchange might be better suited and give you better answers because of the focus of the exchange itself as well as the different people that inhabit it.

It's kind of like going to the doctor. Your orthopedist may help you with your foot pain but another time, an orthopedist might refer you to a podiatrist.  It's not that the orthopedist is incapable of helping you but that he thinks you'd be better served by a different kind of specialist.  It's not a bad thing.

Comment: If a question is on-topic on a site, it shouldn't be migrated to another site where it's also on-topic, even if that site is somehow "better".  The OP chose to ask it here, and we should [respect our community](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).  Migration should only be an option if the question is *off-topic* here, i.e. we would close it outright if we couldn't migrate it somewhere else.  (I'm not saying anything about those two questions in this comment, just responding to what you said about better options.)